# SQL using select with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT manager_id, COUNT(manager_id)
FROM employees
GROUP BY manager_id
HAVING COUNT(manager_id) > 3
```

I have no problem with the code, but,I want to display the manager first name and last name instead of the manager_id, however if I do this, I get the error:
"column 'employees.first_name' is invalid... not contained in either an aggregate function or group by clause". I tried adding first_name and last_name to the group by, output being blank. Tried self join as well.. can't figure out the answer.
The query includes: employee_id, first_name, last_name, manager_id

The query above displays:

```
manager_id (No column name)
100 14
120 8
121 8
122 8
123 8
124 8
145 6
146 6
147 6
148 6
149 6
```

I want:

```
first_name last_name

Bob        Smith
```

Comment: I'm assuming there's a manager table somewhere?

Comment: Show us the query you tried that fails.

Comment: I assume you're using `sql server` and not `mysql`.  Either way please show sample data and expected results.

Comment: This results in nothing:
SELECT e1.first_name, e1.last_name
FROM employees e1 inner join employees e2
 ON e1.manager_id = e2.employee_id
GROUP BY e1.manager_id, e1.first_name, e1.last_name
HAVING COUNT(e2.employee_id) > 3
yes, I am using sql server

Comment: Your query looks pretty close assuming I'm understanding your table structure and sample data (still somewhat guessing though without complete sample data and expected results).  Reverse the columns from `e1` and `e2` in the `on` criteria of the `join` and it might work.  Here's a condensed fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/85497/1

Comment: Thank you so much sqeddes! I can't believe it was such an easy fix, and now I know how to use group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT ISNULL(m.name, 'None') AS ManagerName, COUNT(1)
    FROM employees e
    LEFT JOIN employees m
    on e.manager_id = e.employee_id
    GROUP BY ISNULL(m.name, 'None')
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 3
```

Note count(1) is the same as count(*) but slightly less work on the server.

Comment: `count(1) is the same as count(*) but slightly less work on the server` Any reference on that ?

Comment: @Squirrel, I Googled around and it looks like the difference has been optimized away - in the past it would save a trip to the Columns table.